# how to calculate the elapsed time of a particular event in my application?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, datetime, flash-builder

I need to show in my software the amount of days, hours and minutes that a particular event occurred.

I get a string with the value of the last event and calculating the amount of time that the event occurred.

..

lastEvent: String = lastEventOcorr (); "16.07.2013 19:20:06"

..

example:

Last event occurred: 3 Days 6 Hours 45 Minutes and 42 Seconds

or

Last event occurred: 5 Minutes 30 Seconds

..

There is a practical way to do this calculation?

I really appreciate all the help.

Thank you very much

Comment: This should give you a hint...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869742/java-calendar-date-difference-find-difference-down-to-seconds

Comment: If you can just grab `System.nanotime()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()` at the time of the event, you will have a lot fewer string-parsing headaches.  If it's coming from a log file, then yeah you need to do some date parsing.

Comment: ElDuderino and roippi, Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how to count days, you can add hours and mins to this.

```
            long MILLIS_IN_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

        String lastEvent =  "13.07.2013 10:20:06";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        Date lastEventDate = sdf.parse(lastEvent);
        Date currentDate = new Date();

        long timeElapsed = currentDate.getTime() - lastEventDate.getTime();
        long diffInDays = timeElapsed / MILLIS_IN_DAY; 

        System.out.println(diffInDays);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163/actionscript-3-fastest-way-to-parse-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-to-a-date-object) are several approaches on how to parse your `String` into a `Date` instance.

Afterwards you need to [calculate the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169201/actionscript-3-0-calculate-timespan-between-two-dates) between the parsed `Date` and the current date (`new Date()`).

Finally you can [format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196222/date-formatting-in-actionscript) your resulting difference according to your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest simply doing `System.currentTimeMillis()` at the start of the event and at the end of the event.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
//EVENT
long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();

long difference = stop - start;
```

Then with a little math you can get it in a nicer format.

```
int seconds=(difference/1000)%60;
int minutes=(difference/(1000*60))%60;
int hours=(difference/(1000*60*60))%24;
```

Comment: `System.nanoTime()` is more accurate